# Using Reflection, Invoke Generic Async Method

Tags: c#, generics, async-await

I have a pattern that looks like this when used with known, compile-time types:

```
// given a method like this...
public RSType ComputeSomething(RQType rq) {
    RSType rs = new RSType();
    // do something to rs here, based on rq...
    return rs;
}

// I'm able to do create an event handler like this
eventHandlers.RequestResponseAsync<RQType, RSType>(rq =>
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return ComputeSomething(rq);
    }));
```

And now I'm trying to use reflection so that a function like ComputeSomething can be found at runtime, and then RequestResponseAsync invoked as appropriate.

There is a non-async version, and I've got that working.  For example, given the same ComputeSomething:

```
// get the handler method, and types
var handlerType = Assembly.LoadFrom("SomeAssembly").GetType("SomeNameSpace.SomeClass");
var handlerMethod = handlerType.GetMethod("ComputeSomething");
var handlerParamType = handlerMethod.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault().ParameterType;
var handlerReturnType = handlerMethod.ReturnType;

// get MethodInfo for a generic RequestResponseAsync
var respond = eventHandlers.GetType().GetMethod("RequestResponseAsync");
var genericRespond = respond.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { handlerParamType, handlerReturnType });

// create a delegate to pass to the invocation
var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(handlerParamType, handlerReturnType);
var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, handlerMethod);

// invoke the method
genericRespond.Invoke(eventHandlers, new[] { del });
```

But my brain is too small to figure out how to take it to the next, Async level.

Can someone show me?

Comment: Are you trying to register the delegate using reflection or invoke the handlers?

Comment: I'm trying to invoke a generic method on eventHandlers which registers an event handler - discovered at runtime and determined by the handler parameter - to handle events of a certain type - also discovered at runtime as it is determined by the return type of the handler.  I already have this working, but not where the handler method is run asynchronously via Task.Factory.StartNew()...

Comment: In your example, the delegate starts a new `Task`, returns immediately, and the `Task`'s result gets ignored, so the return type is `void` and you don't need the second type parameter. Can you specify the desired behavior? Should the delegate block and return the result of the task? Should it return the `Task<RSType>`? Full signature of `RequestResponseAsync<,>` would help. Also it's parallel (if it uses default scheduler), not asynchronous, so the name probably shouldn't end with `Async`.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't asked the question in a clear way.  The point is that RequestResponseAsync exists with a signature of: IDisposable RequestResponseAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(Func<TRequest, Task<TResponse>>), and I'm trying to figure out how to invoke it (presumably with reflection) given only a runtime class C, with static method M having signature TResponse C.M(TRequest) and with C.M being called (invoked) inside the Task.  Does that help, or am I still confusing people?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you added a named template function that does the Task.Factory.StartNew.  It seems you want that function to be called via reflection (unless I misunderstood what you are trying to do).

Comment: Well, RequestResponseAsync will be invoked via reflection (because it's generic and the types are only known at runtime) to register the handler, and the handler is created via reflection.  If there is a way to wrap the (eventual) invocation of the handler in a Task, without reflection, I'm all ears.

Comment: What @KC-NH says could be a solution - if you move the `Task.Factory.StartNew` call inside the `RequestResponseAsync` (probably a new overload, or renamed version), the code that you have now should work fine - create a simple delegate, create the generic function, call it; the logic would happen inside.

Comment: I tried to come up with a version that would create the wrapped delegate into `StartNew` with Expression API, but I don't know the API well enough. It should be possible somehow though. The resulting delegate would be `Func<RQType, Task<RSType>>` and could be passed to `RequestResponseAsync` normally. Unfortunately I can't give you working code, so I'll just leave this as a comment.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck providing working code too.  At some point, your generic code needs to work on concrete types.  Is ComputeSomething in a generic class with RSType and RQType as parameters?  Are those types constrained to implement a particular interface?

Comment: ComputeSomething is defined as a static method (just realized I didn't show it as static above) and is discovered at runtime by specifying and assembly, class and method in a config file.  It will have a signature as shown above, except the types RQType and RSType are not known. They are also discovered.  They do happen to both implement a particular interface, but that interface isn't relevant to this problem. The code above does work for the non-parallel/async case so feel free to use that as a starting point.

Comment: I have a quasi-solution, but not exactly what I asked for. I moved the TaskFactory code inside the ComputeSomething method and then changed the signature of it, and then use reflection to work against that.  It works, but it seems like cheating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if someone suggested this a possibility, but I wanted to close the loop.

Here's what I've done, which seems to work.

I've created a generic Func factory function which I then call via reflection.

```
Func<RQ,Task<RS>> RqRsAsyncHandler<RQ,RS>(Func<RQ,RS> handler) 
{
    return (RQ rq) =>
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return handler(rq);
        });
    };
}
```

Then, I basically proceed as before but, instead, pass in the Func created by the function factory.

```
// get a delegate for the actual handler
var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(handlerParamType, handlerReturnType);
var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, handlerMethod);

// get a Func that wraps that handler in a tracer handler
var RqRsAsyncHandlerMethodInfo = typeof(Container).GetMethod("RqRsAsyncHandler");
var RqRsAsyncHandlerMethodInfoGeneric = RqRsAsyncHandlerMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(handlerParamType, handlerReturnType);
var wrapperFunc = RqRsAsyncHandlereMethodInfoGeneric.Invoke(null, new object[] { del });

// get the eventHandlers method
MethodInfo respondMethod = typeof(EventHandlers).GetMethod("RespondAsync");
MethodInfo genericRespondMethod = respondMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { handlerParamType, handlerReturnType });

// invoke the Bus method
genericRespondMethod.Invoke(eventHandlers , new[] { wrapperFunc });
```